# Convert Images into Dicom with python

Tags: dicom, bmp, pydicom

I have problems trying to convert BMP-Images into DICOM. My Python Script list all the BMP Files in the Directory and convert them into a Dicom Dataset. I can run the code but I get a strange result. I don't know what the problem could be, this is my first time working with image processing. Please help me i am lerning:(

```
def convert_bmps_to_dicoms(bmp_dir, dicom_output_dir):
# Create output directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(dicom_output_dir):
    os.makedirs(dicom_output_dir)

# List all BMP files in the directory
bmp_files = [f for f in os.listdir(bmp_dir) if f.endswith('.bmp')]

if not bmp_files:
    print("No BMP files found in the directory.")
    return

for bmp_file in bmp_files:
    # Load BMP image
    bmp_path = os.path.join(bmp_dir, bmp_file)
    image = Image.open(bmp_path)
    image_array = np.array(image)

    # Create DICOM dataset
    ds = FileDataset(os.path.join(dicom_output_dir, f"{os.path.splitext(bmp_file)[0]}.dcm"), {},
                     file_meta=Dataset())
    ds.Modality = 'OT'
    ds.PatientName = "Test^Firstname"
    ds.PatientID = "123456"
    ds.PatientBirthDate = "20000101"
    ds.PatientSex = "F"
    ds.StudyInstanceUID = pydicom.uid.generate_uid()  # Random Study Instance UID
    ds.SeriesInstanceUID = "1.2.826.0.1.3680043.9.3813.1.1.222222"
    ds.SOPInstanceUID = pydicom.uid.generate_uid()
    ds.SamplesPerPixel = 1
    ds.PhotometricInterpretation = "MONOCHROME2"
    ds.Rows = 512  # Set rows to 512
    ds.Columns = 512  # Set columns to 512
    ds.BitsAllocated = 8
    ds.BitsStored = 8
    ds.HighBit = 7
    ds.PixelRepresentation = 0
    ds.PixelData = image_array.tobytes()

    # Add custom attribute for BMP file name
    ds.BMPFileName = bmp_file

    # Write DICOM dataset to file
    ds.save_as(os.path.join(dicom_output_dir, f"{os.path.splitext(bmp_file)[0]}.dcm"))
    print(f"DICOM file {bmp_file}.dcm saved successfully in {dicom_output_dir}.")
```

Comment: You are only setting 4-5 tags while creating dataset. I do not know if your toolkit adds the important tags automatically; but without them, output dataset will be invalid. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/66115428/5779732, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66132967/5779732.

Comment: Also as you said "i cant open the .dcm after converting" does not explain anything. Please edit the question to explain in details what exactly is the problem. If possible, also include dump of output dataset. You can also [search SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdcmtk%5D+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+pixel+data+is%3Aq) to see if that helps...